# What's the best way or practice to align the 3 lines at the bottom like the 3 ones at the top

Tags: website-design, gui-design, design-patterns, best-practice, frontend-development

I have too long text that I don't want to shorten or get rid of and it gets returned to the next line (Avis des tous les clients d'Abricibuis.www.Abricibuis.com)

What's the best practice to align the line below it with the other elements?
I want to be sure I meet UI/UX principles here.

[image: Footer]

Answer (score 2):

Align the horizontal rules. Place the headlines and the text underneath the lines. Let the copy hang from the rules so to speak.

That way you box the content regardless of how long the texts are.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the feedback.
But could you explain what you mean by "hang from the lines"?

Comment: Yes, I've added an image and made some changes to the answer. Basically if you place the copy underneath the ruler both the headline and the copy could vary in lenght. The ruler frame the content and the design will still look rigid.

Answer (score 1):

Align the horizontal rules (divider lines) and have the wrapped text sit on top of it. The three headlines would be bottom-aligned with each other. This provides visual consistency.